# React destructuring state assignment

Tags: reactjs

I have a program where I have a menu that can toggle the view of any item on screen.
I was originally using `useState` to toggle each individual component

example:

```
const [buttonA, setButtonA] = useState(false)
const [buttonB, setButtonB] = useState(false)
//...etc
```

This functioned correctly when implemented. However, now I've been tasked with using a single object to handle all keys from Props in a class component:

example:

```
      layers:
        {
          propA: props.propA,
          propB: props.PropB,
//..etc
}
```

I have also implemented a function to show or hide an element on screen. It takes the JSON key and updates the layer view based on the toggle.

```
  showHideHandler = (key, value) => {
    const newLayers = { ...layers };
    newLayers[key] = value;
    this.setState({ layers: newLayers });
  };
```

I use this function in a modal to control the show/hide feature like this:

```
  <Button
     className={style.selector}
     onClick={() => showHideHandler('propA', !layers.propA)}
     > I AM PROP A
</Button>
```

Finally I am passing the prop values into a component like this for example:

```
{layers.propA ? (
<p> Visible </p>
):(
<p> Invisible</p>
)}
```

This toggle function works that I am able to show and hide element. However, the following problem is occurring.

When I first click on any button. The first thing that happens is that *all* the elements are hidden on the screen as if all the states are being set to hide. If I click the button a second time, the original component I want to hide shows the correct show hide action but all other items are still hidden.

I went back to check my toggle function `const newLayers = { ...layers };` and made the following update to the newLayers const: `const newLayers = this.setState.layers`

```
  showHideHandler = (key, value) => {
    const newLayers = this.setState.layers;
    newLayers[key] = value;
    this.setState({ layers: newLayers });
  };
```

This now returns the error `must use restructuring state assignment` which shows the following error in the browser: `Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state`

I'm a bit stuck at this point and any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is not the correct way to setState `const newLayers = this.setState.layers;` also you should only `this` inside class component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Red Baron said, `const newLayers = this.setState.layers;` is non-sense.
You should mutate `setState`'s first argument (representing the previous state) to update your state :

```js
const showHideHandler = (key, value) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    layers: {
      ...prevState.layers,
      [key]: value,
    }
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure of the logic I created for the showHideHandler, but your solution fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a warning is informing you to use a functional state update.

```
showHideHandler = (key, value) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    // spread previous layers state into new object
    const newLayers = { ...prevState.layers };
    newLayers[key] = value;
    return { layers: newLayers };
  });
};
```

Or more succinctly

```
showHideHandler = (key, value) => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      layers: {
        ...prevState.layers,
        [key]: value,
      },
    };
  });
};
```

Comment: In the second way, you probably meant to return the object for `layers` state property.

Comment: @aquinq Right, I typically use the shorter arrow function return, but tried to keep the syntax similar to that used by the OP so it wasn't *too much* a change.